# What should I do with my bounty message on my question that states something that isn't true?

Tags: support, specific-question, bounty

Recently I made this question: [How do I maintain a live video stream playing if I change tabs in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76165949/how-do-i-maintain-a-live-video-stream-playing-if-i-change-tabs-in-chrome?noredirect=1#comment134435815_76165949)

I've put a large bounty on it, because I had been trying to solve this problem for around 3 weeks, and I wasn't getting anywhere.

Fortunately, I finally found what the problem was and I saw that what I had written wasn't true. I was misled in some moment of the debugging to think a simple page with only a video tag in it had the problem. It hasn't. It works fine with a simple video tag.

Now I have a 200 point bounty on a question that is misleading and wrong.

Yet several people upvoted the question, leading me to think that some users may be experiencing the same problem and are also being misled by the message.

So I opted to add a paragraph explaining that I have found part of the question isn't true and that I was misled in some moment, that the problem doesn't occur the way I said it did and including an answer explaining how I solved the real problem.

But I also thought that it may be too confusing and maybe the best option would be to delete it altogether. But as I tried to do this I saw this intimidating message "don't delete answered questions, bla bla". So I maintained the explanations and left the message there.

Did I choose the right way to deal with this? What is the best thing to do in this case?

Comment: eh, i wouldn't read into the upvotes so heavily, that's just what happens when bounties are applied to a post. The more important fact is there are existing answers. You cannot edit a question such that existing answers are invalidated.

Comment: You can post an answer yourself as part of addressing this.

Comment: Could you have changed the question to fix the mistake, without invalidating the existing answer?

Comment: The person who answered the question deleted the answer. There's only one answer now and it's mine. Do you think I should change the question to reflect the real problem or leave it that way ?